# How to compare two string values as integers?

Tags: javascript

I am converting and comparing two string values using

```
if (parseInt(x)!=parseInt(y)) {
```

The problem is if values are `x="9"` and `y="09"` the test returns `false`.

How can I get fix this ?

Comment: Btw.: `9` and `09` are considered equal as `09` is not a valid number in octal and as such is interpreted as a decimal.

Comment: Really? FF parses it to zero.

Comment: @spender I’m using Firefox too; tested it in the web console, scratchpad, Firebug and JSTerm now. Same result, `09 == 9`.

Comment: That's strange because in my web console `parseInt("09") == 0`

Comment: Okay… strings; I was using numbers, as `y=09` does not look like a string assignment to me.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use this :

```
if(parseInt(x, 10)!=parseInt(y, 10))
```

If you don't precise the radix, "09" is parsed as octal (this gives 0).

[MDN documentation about parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Note that you shouldn't even rely on this interpretation when working with octal representations :

> **ECMAScript 5 Removes Octal Interpretation**
>
> The ECMAScript 5 specification of the function parseInt no longer
>   allows implementations to treat Strings beginning with a 0 character
>   as octal values. ECMAScript 5 states:
>
> The parseInt function produces an integer value dictated by
>   interpretation of the contents of the string argument according to the
>   specified radix. Leading white space in string is ignored. If radix is
>   undefined or 0, it is assumed to be 10 except when the number begins
>   with the character pairs 0x or 0X, in which case a radix of 16 is
>   assumed. If radix is 16, number may also optionally begin with the
>   character pairs 0x or 0X.
>
> This differs from ECMAScript 3, which discouraged but allowed octal
>   interpretation.
>
> Since many implementations have not adopted this behavior as of 2011,
>   and because older browsers must be supported, always specify a radix.

Simply :

> always specify a radix

Comment: And `09` is not a valid octal number so it is always interpreted as a decimal. `010` and `10` would have been a better example.

Comment: @poke - It's not interpreted as a decimal. It's interpreted as an octal but since it's not a valid octal number it just returns `0`.

Comment: @JamesAllardice Meh, was using numbers (not strings), so ignore me :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the radix explicitelly to 10 otherwise it assume it is 8 (javascript bad parts):

```
parseInt(x,10)
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp

> If the string begins with "0", the radix is 8 (octal). This feature is
>   deprecated