# Array length undefined after split

Tags: javascript, split

I'd like to split a string ("1,2,3") and return it as an int array so I wrote the following function:

```
function stringToIntArray(string) {
    var split = {};
    split = string.split(',');

    var selected = {};

    for (var i = 0; i <= split.length; i++) {
        selected[i] = split[i];
    }

    return selected;
}
```

However split.length is always undefinied. Where's my mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var selected = {};
```

doesn't build an array but an object, which has no `length` property.

You can fix your code by replacing it with

```
var selected = [];
```

If you want to return an array of numbers, you can change your code to

```
function stringToIntArray(string) {
    var split = string.split(',');
    var selected = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
        selected.push(parseInt(split[i], 10));
    }
    return selected;
}
```

Note that I replaced `<=` with `<` in your loop.

Note also that for modern browsers, you can use the [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function to make it simpler :

```
function stringToIntArray(string) {
    return string.split(',').map(function(v){ return parseInt(v, 10) });
}
```

Comment: This does not really account for the `int` part, but then, neither does OPs code. +1

Comment: @elusive I had missed the "int" part at first reading. I edited. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you took me to the right track:
for (i in split) {
        //Replace string by int
        split[i] = parseInt(split[i]);
    }
Is working nicely. Thank you.

Comment: Don't forget the radix (`10`) : you'll avoid strange bugs (parsing as octal for example) on some old browsers. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598413/how-to-compare-two-string-values-as-integers).